# i want to exporting data from mysql to mongodb for every 6 hours that is newly created data

Tags: mysql

I want to export data from **mysql to mongod**b  for **every 6 hours** that is newly created data then how to write a query for every 6 hours the newly created data goes  from mysql to mongodb please suggest me ?

I am working on databases like mysql and mongodb

I've tried this example :

```
select * FROM demo WHERE 
           (currentdate between '2017-03-17 13:36:39.00000' 
                            and '2017-03-17 13:37:39.00000');
```

(then how to retrieve the data, that is newly created data in a table for every 6 hours in mysql)